# Django Authenticate always returns None with correct credentials also

Tags: python, django, authentication

I was creating a login and registration page for my project and was using the Django MySQL database for login and creating users the signup was done correctly but the login function is not working for me.

PS: The is_active is Set True but still this is not working

**With all correct info, it [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeHA3.jpg) None. I have given all the necessary parts of the file and codes**

I tried everything but nothing seems to work also tried some of the solutions listed on StackOverflow but still, nothing worked for me.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Description
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    d = Description.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'des':d})
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first']
        last_name = request.POST['last']
        user_name = request.POST['user']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['password1']
        pass2 = request.POST['password2']
        if pass1 == pass2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                print("Email taken")
            elif User.objects.filter(username=user_name).exists():
                print("Username taken")
            else:        
                user = User.objects.create_user(username = user_name, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, password=pass1, email=email)
                user.save()
                print("User created")
        else:
            print("Password Not Matching")  
        return redirect('/')      
    else:
        return render(request,'signup.html')   
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']         
        password = request.POST['password']
        print(email,password)
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print("Logged in")
        else:
            print("not logged in")    
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django `authenticate` method allows for authenticating using only username.
You can get the user's username from the User model using the user's email

```
username = User.objects.get(email=email).username
password = request.POST.get('password')
```

Replace this `user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)`

with this `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`

Comment: You have answered the same thing as i did, what is different in your answer you think?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is django's default authentication mechanism don't allow you authenticate using `email`, you can only authenticate user using `username` .
either way, you can get the user's username from the `User model` using his email and then you can authenticate user.

```
    def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            username = ''
            try:
                username = User.objects.get(email=email).username
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return HttpResponse("Invalid")
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print("Logged in")
            else:
                print("not logged in")
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid")
```

Also dont store password directly, always user standard `set_password()` function of django

```
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                print("Email taken")
            elif User.objects.filter(username=user_name).exists():
                print("Username taken")
            else:        
                user = User.objects.create_user(username = user_name, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, email=email)
                user.set_password(pass1)
                user.save()
                print("User created")
```

Comment: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given I am getting this error message this time

Comment: Your login function have the same name login. Please change it to something else like user_login then it will work fine

Comment: if you find this answer helpful feel free to give a selection and thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your signup method. You should not give `password` to the init function. You should use User's `set_password` method.

In your sign_up view remove `password=pass1` at the line where you are creating User object. And after that before saving the user, add `user.set_password(pass1)`.

Hope this helps!